# Delete albums/files in Noise

Tags: release-loki, music

The built-in music player is elementary OS works in a weird manner. I copied few albums in the default folder, Music but since then I can not get rid of any. There is no delete option in Noise and if I just remove it from the folder it still appears in Noise. How can I delete not wanted contents anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/noise/+bug/1181823) that could be related to this issue... If you are stuck though do this:

As an instant fix, close the app, then you can delete the entire database in ~/.local/share/noise/

```
rm ~/.local/share/noise/database*
```

Then relaunch and it should re-scan